# Azure Advisor - how do I know if a recommendatio has been completed?

Tags: azure

When using Azure Advisor, can I distinguish situation when a recommendation has disappeared from the system because I've completed it from a situation when it didn't make sense anymore ? In both cases, Azure Advisor simply doesn't show it on the Recommendation List.

Comment: If you click on a recommendation, you have all the recommendations details. You have the option to see whether any of these were postponed or dismissed. Isn't this what you are looking for?

Comment: Not really. My case is: let's assume that I've a cost saving recommendations. I've completed a few of them, I'd like to see how much money I've saved. Right now, if a recommendation simply disappears from the system. it's been either completed or for example is stoppped making sense (like I've deleted a vm that's not used vs someone has started using the vm)

Comment: I looked at the Azure Feedback site and did not find anything on their radar for a use case like yours. In short, Azure Advisor should give the ability to show inactive recommandations along with a field to indicate whether it was resolved or is simply not pertinent at this point in time.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am looking for. Currently the status of recommendation is unfortunately unknown.